# How to create an iterator pipeline in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, pipeline

Is there a library or recommended way for creating an iterator pipeline in Python?

For example:

```
>>>all_items().get("created_by").location().surrounding_cities()
```

I also want to be able to access attributes of the objects in the iterators. In the above example, `all_items()` returns an iterator of items, and the items have different creators.

The `.get("created_by")` then returns the "created_by" attribute of the items (which are people), and then `location()` returns the city of each person, and then pipes it to `surrounding_cities()`, which returns all an iterator of the surrounding cities for each location (so the end result is a large list of surrounding cities).

Comment: You're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/python-pipeline/

Comment: I'm trying to see what it would take to emulate Gremlin in Python:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wpTtEBK4-E

Answer (score 4):

Aren't you just processing an iterator?  The natural way to use an iterator in Python is the for loop:

```
for item in all_items():
    item.get("created_by").location().surrounding_cities()
```

There are other possibilities such as list comprehensions which may make more sense depending upon what you're doing (usually makes more sense if you're trying to generate a list as your output).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look up how to implement pipes with [coroutines in python](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/), more specifically this [pipe example](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/copipe.py)

If you implemented your functions according to the example above, then your code would be something like this (for simplicity, I suppose you'll want to print those cities):

```
all_items(get_location(get_creators(get_surrounding_cities(printer()))))
```

Comment: Why not `all_items(get_creators(get_location(get_surrounding_cities(printer()))))` ? Is there a reason for `all_items` and `get_creators` to behave differently than `get_location` and `get_surrounding_cities`?

Comment: Actually you're right, no need to behave differently, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

in your example you only really have two iterator methods, `all_items` and `surrounding_cities` so you could do pretty well with just `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

cities = chain.from_iterable(
    item.get("created_by").location().surrounding_cities() for item in all_items()
)
```

`cities` would then be an iterator listing all the surrounding cities for the items