# chain the function as shell pipe command in python

Tags: python, function, shell, pipe

In Unix/linux shell we can:

```
seq 0 100 | head -10 | awk 'NF%2==0' | awk 'NF%2==1' | rev
```

Now I defined:

```
seqsrc = list(range(0,100))

def all(src): return src
def head(src, count, offset = 0): return src[:count]
def tail(src, count, offset = 0): return src[-count:]
def odd(src): return [x for x in src if x % 2 != 0]
def even(src): return [x for x in src if x % 2 == 0]
def reverse(src): return src[::1]
...
#def other_sequence_manpulation_method()
```

Here are my questions:

1.
How can I get shell pipe like grammar in python?

```
seqdst = all(seqsrc).head(10).odd().even().reverse()
```

2.
For some reason I want to enumerate all possible combinations of those simple functions I defined, can I do it with itertools.product() to generate combinations - EDIT: as well as for the Seq class solution below?

```
possible_head_limit = [10,20,30]

all(seqsrc).head(10)                    # 10 is one item in possible_head_limit
all(seqsrc).head(10).odd()
all(seqsrc).head(10).odd().even()
all(seqsrc).head(10).odd().even().reverse()
all(seqsrc).head(10).even()
all(seqsrc).head(10).even().odd()
....
all(seqsrc).head(20)                    # 20 is one item in possible_head_limit

all(seqsrc).head(20).odd()
...
```

3:
Suppose `seqsrc = range(0,10)` then `head(20)` may return same as `head(10)` or sometime it is meanless

```
all(seqsrc).head(20).odd().even().reverse()  
# = all(seqsrc).head(10).odd().even().reverse() 
# = all(seqsrc).head(11).odd().even().reverse()
# ...
```

Can I add control function in the method chain, then I can control the mean of the return?

```
ignore_insufficient(True).all(seqsrc).head(20).odd().even().reverse()
ignore_insufficient(False).all(seqsrc).head(20).odd().even().reverse()  # it will print some sort of error

# or even I can control each function I defined?
ignore_insufficient(True).all(seqsrc).\
ignore_insufficient(True).head(20).\
ignore_insufficient(False).tail(10)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `.odd().even()` is unlikely to be very useful.

Comment: @Johnsyweb; yes, just a sample to say what I want.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188558/how-to-create-an-iterator-pipeline-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many questions in your post and I'm not certain to understand them all. However, here is a starting point.

Chainable methods are usually implemented by designing classes with methods that return new instances of the class itself. This allows to call further methods from the return value of previous methods.

Therefore, you can define a `Seq` class as follows:

```
class Seq(object):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.seq)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.seq)
    def all(self):
        return Seq(self.seq[:])
    def head(self, count):
        return Seq(self.seq[:count])
    def tail(self, count):
        return Seq(self.seq[-count:])
    def odd(self):
        return Seq(self.seq[1::2])
    def even(self):
        return Seq(self.seq[::2])
    def reverse(self):
        return Seq(self.seq[::-1])
```

And use it like:

```
>>> s = Seq(range(0, 100))
>>> print s.head(10).odd().even().reverse()
[9, 5, 1]
```

Note that this can be improved in many ways. For instance, in the Javascript world, [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)'s chainable methods actually push their results into a stack, thus allowing *backtracking* in the history of calls and restoring a previous context. See [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) for details.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, thanks for your help, is that means I have to define all the sequence functions inside of the class defination?

Comment: @user478514, indeed, it would probably be best to do so. You *could* use free functions that take and return `Seq` instances instead of methods (think `def head(s, count): return Seq(s.seq[:count])` and `head(s, 10).odd(s).even(s).reverse(s)`), but it would be arguably uglier.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, humm, thanks, btw, I think my 3rd question can be solved by define it inside of class `def ignore_insufficient(self,flag) : self.flag = flag; return Seq(seq.seq[:count])` then test length `self.seq` on each other function based on the flag value. but, I still have no idea for the 2nd quetion, maybe I have to list all function name in class Seq?

Comment: @user478514, your second question is probably worth a post by itself (I'd go with a method decorator but others might have better answers). Concerning your third question, the same might apply, but I can't be sure since I still don't understand what `ignore_insufficient()` is supposed to do :)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, aplogize for my poor english -_-b, I should study more harder on school:-), `ignore_insufficient()` just means if the source sequence is less than the `head()` limited, for example,  `head(10, [1,2,3,4,5])`, sure it will only print `[1,2,3,4,5]`, but I don't think it is meanful sometime, so I want to add a flag to control it - allow this or not

Comment: @user478514, understood, then you're on the right track with your proposed strategy (add a boolean flag member to the `Seq` class). However, you should `return self` rather than a new instance of `Seq` in your `ignore_insufficient()` method, or the flag will be reset in the returned instance and the method will appear to do nothing. Also, consider naming your flag something else than `flag` ;)